# CouchDB get all databases and their last changes

Tags: json, database, get, couchdb

I know that i can get all databases with

```
GET _all_dbs
```

and also the last change of a database by

```
GET /{db}/_changes?descending=true&limit=1
```

the result will be like:

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "seq":112,
         "id":"20e3480f5db4802d94a8193ac2246ae7",
         "changes":[  
            {  
               "rev":"2-fb8204608047ce016282acbf3239cd01"
            }
         ],
         "deleted":true
      }
   ],
   "last_seq":112
}
```

Now is it possible to combine these statements to get something like:

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "db1":"1-fb8204608047ce016282acbf3239cd01"
      },
      {  
         "db2":"2-fb8204608047ce016282acbf3239cd02"
      },
      {  
         "db3":"2-fb8204608047ce016282acbf3239cd03"
      },
      {  
         "db4":"2-fb8204608047ce016282acbf3239cd04"
      }
   ]
}
```

where "db1" is a database name and "2-fb8204608047ce016282acbf3239cd04" is the last _rev of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism to make any query across multiple database in couchdb.

You can however do this from your application by joining the result of multiple queries.

Comment: Thank you Eloims, that was also what i found on my research. Maybe useful and interesting for others - you can map documents in other documents https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Linked_documents

Comment: Updated link about [Linked Documents](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/ddocs/views/joins.html#linked-documents)